# How to run spoon in only one device

Tags: android, maven, spoon, android-instrumentation

I have the situation where the tests can't be run in 2 different devices at the same time. I need to keep the two devices attached for another reason. How can I execute **"mvn spoon:run"** and run the tests in only one device instead of all of them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the *devices* option:

```
spoon {
  devices = ['333236E9AE5800EC']
}
```

Found at the Spoon Gradle Plugin [documentation site](https://github.com/stanfy/spoon-gradle-plugin).